# Re-autosign certificates in Puppet CA

Tags: ssl, certificate, puppet

I'm using an [autosign script](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/3.7/reference/ssl_autosign.html#policy-based-autosigning) in Puppet to sign certificates. This is actually working, but I'm experimenting a problem when a machine try to request again a certificate (eg. ssl directory is removed). In this cases, a cached certificate is used and obviously does not match with the certificate created by the agent. Here is an example output:

```
Info: Creating a new SSL key for foo.bar.com
Info: Caching certificate for ca
Info: Caching certificate for foo.bar.com
Error: Could not request certificate: The certificate retrieved from the master does not match the agent's private key.
Certificate fingerprint: 41:B7:ED:3C:EC:A9:EF:A9:51:8C:6C:46:94:B1:30:09:72:2F:CC:D2:13:BA:A5:63:A7:2D:C5:FB:BD:DF:A5:B4
```

I don't want/can't remove certificates by hand executing puppet cert clean so I tried to use [allow_duplicate_certs](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/3.7/reference/configuration.html#allowduplicatecerts) but [seems to be buggy](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-2354) since... quite a lot time.

Do you know any other option to re-autosign a certificate when the host already have a signed certificate in the CA?

Comment: Have you considered the approach suggested by Eric Sorenson in [his comment on the bug report you linked](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-2354?focusedCommentId=124076&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-124076)?  Basically, he suggests that your autosign script can clear out the old cert if it chooses to issue a new one.

Comment: The problem is that the script is not executed because there is a certificate already in the CA. As you can see in the output I posted, it tries to match the new certificate with the one in the CA. Would be different if the script was executed before caching anything...

Comment: I have no solution to suggest other than to make clearing out old certs a step in your deployment procedure.  I can imagine ways that you might automate such a thing, but none [working] built in to Puppet.  If you happen to be seeing this problem on Puppet 4, however, then you might draw renewed PL attention to the matter by reporting that on the ticket.  Most of PL's development efforts are on Puppet 4 these days.

Comment: Any idea to automate it is welcomed actually. Too soon for us to migrate to Puppet 4...

Comment: One idea: maintain a file of deployment timestamps per certname, somewhere that the master can read it or at least retrieve it.  Schedule a periodic job on the master (/ca host) that compares existing certs to the timestamps and cleans out stale certs.

Comment: Another idea: if you are using MCollective in your environment, then have your deployment / spin-up / first-boot script use that to run an appropriate `puppet cert clean` command on the master.

Comment: Another idea: if you happen to be running a web server on the master, implement the certificate cleaning via a web request that can be performed at deployment time.

Comment: Another idea: write your own network service that can run on the master to handle certificate cleaning requests.  (Not as hard as it might sound for basic functionality, but properly securing such a service might be an issue.)